# What is modified complex action function and how does it apply to an integral?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

What is  modified complex action function and how does it apply to an integral?
I am very confused on where to start? Could Recommend some Literature to see how to learn what it is,the refenences are too hard to understand for me(I am an undergrad)
https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2014.0943 equation (1.17)

Comment: It's a little heady but the wiki article on the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics might have some answers. There are close connections between heat equations and Schrodinger equations.

Comment: @CameronWilliams could you link the article please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation

Comment: @CameronWilliams doesnt have any concrete material for me to understand

Comment: The resources at the bottom of the page might help.

Comment: I been reading 
Complex Analysis and Dynamical Systems II: A Conference in Honor of Professor Lawrence Zalcman's Sixtieth Birthday, June 9-12, 2003, Nahariya,it mentions the modified complex action function but doesnt state its physical significance,it just mentions the formula?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128199/discussion-between-scroo0ooge-and-cameron-williams).